# UnsatisfiedLink error :Native method not found findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I am working on android project related to android JNI and NDK . I have loade all the .so files required for the project.But it is still showing error that ***UnsatisfiedLink Error, 
Native method not found,
findLibrary retuned null,
java.lang.Runtime,***

My log image is given below

[image]

It is clearly seen from the image.Library is added but why it is giving error?

There is one more file which is having declaration of native function in Utilities.java file

My code is

```
package me.frankly.utils;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.util.Log;

public class Utilities {

    static
    {
        try
        {

            System.loadLibrary("videocompression");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
    }

    public native static int convertVideoFrame(ByteBuffer src, ByteBuffer dest,
            int destFormat, int width, int height, int padding, int swap);

    }
```

Native code :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <libyuv.h>
#include <utils.h>

enum COLOR_FORMATTYPE {
    COLOR_FormatMonochrome = 1,
    COLOR_Format8bitRGB332 = 2,
    COLOR_Format12bitRGB444 = 3,
    COLOR_Format16bitARGB4444 = 4,
    COLOR_Format16bitARGB1555 = 5,
    COLOR_Format16bitRGB565 = 6,
    COLOR_Format16bitBGR565 = 7,
    COLOR_Format18bitRGB666 = 8,
    COLOR_Format18bitARGB1665 = 9,
    COLOR_Format19bitARGB1666 = 10,
    COLOR_Format24bitRGB888 = 11,
    COLOR_Format24bitBGR888 = 12,
    COLOR_Format24bitARGB1887 = 13,
    COLOR_Format25bitARGB1888 = 14,
    COLOR_Format32bitBGRA8888 = 15,
    COLOR_Format32bitARGB8888 = 16,
    COLOR_FormatYUV411Planar = 17,
    COLOR_FormatYUV411PackedPlanar = 18,
    COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar = 19,
    COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar = 20,
    COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar = 21,
    COLOR_FormatYUV422Planar = 22,
    COLOR_FormatYUV422PackedPlanar = 23,
    COLOR_FormatYUV422SemiPlanar = 24,
    COLOR_FormatYCbYCr = 25,
    COLOR_FormatYCrYCb = 26,
    COLOR_FormatCbYCrY = 27,
    COLOR_FormatCrYCbY = 28,
    COLOR_FormatYUV444Interleaved = 29,
    COLOR_FormatRawBayer8bit = 30,
    COLOR_FormatRawBayer10bit = 31,
    COLOR_FormatRawBayer8bitcompressed = 32,
    COLOR_FormatL2 = 33,
    COLOR_FormatL4 = 34,
    COLOR_FormatL8 = 35,
    COLOR_FormatL16 = 36,
    COLOR_FormatL24 = 37,
    COLOR_FormatL32 = 38,
    COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar = 39,
    COLOR_FormatYUV422PackedSemiPlanar = 40,
    COLOR_Format18BitBGR666 = 41,
    COLOR_Format24BitARGB6666 = 42,
    COLOR_Format24BitABGR6666 = 43,

    COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar = 0x7f000100,
    COLOR_FormatSurface = 0x7F000789,
    COLOR_QCOM_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar = 0x7fa30c00
};

int isSemiPlanarYUV(int colorFormat) {
    switch (colorFormat) {
    case COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
    case COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:
        return 0;
    case COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar:
    case COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
    case COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

JNIEXPORT int Java_me_frankly_utils_Utilities_convertVideoFrame(
        JNIEnv *env, jclass class, jobject src, jobject dest, int destFormat,
        int width, int height, int padding, int swap)
    {
    if (!src || !dest || !destFormat) {
        return 0;
    }

    jbyte *srcBuff = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, src);
    jbyte *destBuff = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, dest);

    int half_width = (width + 1) / 2;
    int half_height = (height + 1) / 2;

    if (!isSemiPlanarYUV(destFormat))
    {
        if (!swap)
        {
            ARGBToI420(srcBuff, width * 4, destBuff, width,
                    destBuff + width * height + half_width * half_height
                            + padding * 5 / 4, half_width,
                    destBuff + width * height + padding, half_width, width,
                    height);
        }
        else
        {
            ARGBToI420(srcBuff, width * 4, destBuff, width,
                    destBuff + width * height + padding, half_width,
                    destBuff + width * height + half_width * half_height
                            + padding * 5 / 4, half_width, width, height);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!swap)
        {
            ARGBToNV21(srcBuff, width * 4, destBuff, width,
                    destBuff + width * height + padding, half_width * 2, width,
                    height);
        }
        else
        {
            ARGBToNV12(srcBuff, width * 4, destBuff, width,
                    destBuff + width * height + padding, half_width * 2, width,
                    height);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This is my .h file generated by javah -jni

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class me_frankly_utils_Utilities */

#ifndef _Included_me_frankly_utils_Utilities
#define _Included_me_frankly_utils_Utilities
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     me_frankly_utils_Utilities
 * Method:    convertVideoFrame
 * Signature: (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;IIIII)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_me_frankly_utils_Utilities_convertVideoFrame
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject, jobject, jint, jint, jint, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Here is my Android.mk file code

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE    :=  videocompression
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -w -std=gnu99 -O2 -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -DBSD=1 -ffast-math -O2 -funroll-loops
#LOCAL_LDLIBS   := -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -ljnigraphics -llog

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
./opus/src/opus.c \
./opus/src/opus_decoder.c \
./opus/src/opus_encoder.c \
./opus/src/opus_multistream.c \
./opus/src/opus_multistream_encoder.c \
./opus/src/opus_multistream_decoder.c \
./opus/src/repacketizer.c \
./opus/src/analysis.c \
./opus/src/mlp.c \
./opus/src/mlp_data.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/silk/CNG.c \
./opus/silk/code_signs.c \
./opus/silk/init_decoder.c \
./opus/silk/decode_core.c \
./opus/silk/decode_frame.c \
./opus/silk/decode_parameters.c \
./opus/silk/decode_indices.c \
./opus/silk/decode_pulses.c \
./opus/silk/decoder_set_fs.c \
./opus/silk/dec_API.c \
./opus/silk/enc_API.c \
./opus/silk/encode_indices.c \
./opus/silk/encode_pulses.c \
./opus/silk/gain_quant.c \
./opus/silk/interpolate.c \
./opus/silk/LP_variable_cutoff.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_decode.c \
./opus/silk/NSQ.c \
./opus/silk/NSQ_del_dec.c \
./opus/silk/PLC.c \
./opus/silk/shell_coder.c \
./opus/silk/tables_gain.c \
./opus/silk/tables_LTP.c \
./opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.c \
./opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_WB.c \
./opus/silk/tables_other.c \
./opus/silk/tables_pitch_lag.c \
./opus/silk/tables_pulses_per_block.c \
./opus/silk/VAD.c \
./opus/silk/control_audio_bandwidth.c \
./opus/silk/quant_LTP_gains.c \
./opus/silk/VQ_WMat_EC.c \
./opus/silk/HP_variable_cutoff.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_encode.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_VQ.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_unpack.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_del_dec_quant.c \
./opus/silk/process_NLSFs.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_LR_to_MS.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_MS_to_LR.c \
./opus/silk/check_control_input.c \
./opus/silk/control_SNR.c \
./opus/silk/init_encoder.c \
./opus/silk/control_codec.c \
./opus/silk/A2NLSF.c \
./opus/silk/ana_filt_bank_1.c \
./opus/silk/biquad_alt.c \
./opus/silk/bwexpander_32.c \
./opus/silk/bwexpander.c \
./opus/silk/debug.c \
./opus/silk/decode_pitch.c \
./opus/silk/inner_prod_aligned.c \
./opus/silk/lin2log.c \
./opus/silk/log2lin.c \
./opus/silk/LPC_analysis_filter.c \
./opus/silk/LPC_inv_pred_gain.c \
./opus/silk/table_LSF_cos.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF2A.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_stabilize.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.c \
./opus/silk/pitch_est_tables.c \
./opus/silk/resampler.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_down2_3.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_down2.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_AR2.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_down_FIR.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_IIR_FIR.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_up2_HQ.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_rom.c \
./opus/silk/sigm_Q15.c \
./opus/silk/sort.c \
./opus/silk/sum_sqr_shift.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_decode_pred.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_encode_pred.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_find_predictor.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_quant_pred.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/silk/fixed/LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/corrMatrix_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/encode_frame_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_LPC_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_LTP_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_pitch_lags_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_pred_coefs_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/noise_shape_analysis_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/prefilter_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/process_gains_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/regularize_correlations_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy16_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/solve_LS_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/warped_autocorrelation_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/apply_sine_window_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/k2a_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/k2a_Q16_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/vector_ops_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/schur64_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/schur_FIX.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/celt/bands.c \
./opus/celt/celt.c \
./opus/celt/celt_encoder.c \
./opus/celt/celt_decoder.c \
./opus/celt/cwrs.c \
./opus/celt/entcode.c \
./opus/celt/entdec.c \
./opus/celt/entenc.c \
./opus/celt/kiss_fft.c \
./opus/celt/laplace.c \
./opus/celt/mathops.c \
./opus/celt/mdct.c \
./opus/celt/modes.c \
./opus/celt/pitch.c \
./opus/celt/celt_lpc.c \
./opus/celt/quant_bands.c \
./opus/celt/rate.c \
./opus/celt/vq.c \
./opus/celt/arm/armcpu.c \
./opus/celt/arm/arm_celt_map.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/ogg/bitwise.c \
./opus/ogg/framing.c \
./opus/opusfile/info.c \
./opus/opusfile/internal.c \
./opus/opusfile/opusfile.c \
./opus/opusfile/stream.c





LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    := \
./opus/include \
./opus/silk \
./opus/silk/fixed \
./opus/celt \
./opus/ \
./opus/opusfile \
./libyuv/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./libjpeg/jcapimin.c \
./libjpeg/jcapistd.c \
./libjpeg/armv6_idct.S \
./libjpeg/jccoefct.c \
./libjpeg/jccolor.c \
./libjpeg/jcdctmgr.c \
./libjpeg/jchuff.c \
./libjpeg/jcinit.c \
./libjpeg/jcmainct.c \
./libjpeg/jcmarker.c \
./libjpeg/jcmaster.c \
./libjpeg/jcomapi.c \
./libjpeg/jcparam.c \
./libjpeg/jcphuff.c \
./libjpeg/jcprepct.c \
./libjpeg/jcsample.c \
./libjpeg/jctrans.c \
./libjpeg/jdapimin.c \
./libjpeg/jdapistd.c \
./libjpeg/jdatadst.c \
./libjpeg/jdatasrc.c \
./libjpeg/jdcoefct.c \
./libjpeg/jdcolor.c \
./libjpeg/jddctmgr.c \
./libjpeg/jdhuff.c \
./libjpeg/jdinput.c \
./libjpeg/jdmainct.c \
./libjpeg/jdmarker.c \
./libjpeg/jdmaster.c \
./libjpeg/jdmerge.c \
./libjpeg/jdphuff.c \
./libjpeg/jdpostct.c \
./libjpeg/jdsample.c \
./libjpeg/jdtrans.c \
./libjpeg/jerror.c \
./libjpeg/jfdctflt.c \
./libjpeg/jfdctfst.c \
./libjpeg/jfdctint.c \
./libjpeg/jidctflt.c \
./libjpeg/jidctfst.c \
./libjpeg/jidctint.c \
./libjpeg/jidctred.c \
./libjpeg/jmemmgr.c \
./libjpeg/jmemnobs.c \
./libjpeg/jquant1.c \
./libjpeg/jquant2.c \
./libjpeg/jutils.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./libyuv/source/compare_common.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare_neon.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare_posix.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare_win.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_from_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_from.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_jpeg.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_to_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_to_i420.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert.cc \
./libyuv/source/cpu_id.cc \
./libyuv/source/format_conversion.cc \
./libyuv/source/mjpeg_decoder.cc \
./libyuv/source/mjpeg_validate.cc \
./libyuv/source/planar_functions.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_mips.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_neon.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_neon64.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_any.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_common.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_mips.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_neon.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_neon64.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_posix.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_win.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_common.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_mips.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_neon.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_neon64.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_posix.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_win.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale.cc \
./libyuv/source/video_common.cc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./jni.c \
./audio.c \
./utils.c \
./image.c \
./video.c \
./fake.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78325/discussion-on-question-by-udit-unsatisfiedlink-error-native-method-not-found-fi).

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkerror is solved by this.Build your .so file again by "ndk_build"